# Punctuation Replacement Python

Tags: python, string, methods, replace

Learning python and can't seem to figure out why my code doesn't work, I'm trying to replace all punctuation in a given string with a space. Here's my code...

```
import string 

def replace(text):

    for char in text:
        if char in string.punctuation:
            text.replace(char, " ")

    return text 




test = "Ok! Where, to now?"


#expected "Ok  Where  to now  " 
#returned "Ok! Where to now?"
```

Any input is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replace` doesn't modify the string passed into the first argument (`str`ing objects are immutable, meaning the object itself can't be modified). So you'll need to update the `text` variable with the return value of the replace operation yourself:

```
text = text.replace(char, " ")
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) (emphasis mine):

> **Return a copy** of string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.

Answer (score 0):

As a note about efficiency, python will create a new copy of the entire string every time text.replace is called.  A better option is to convert thing string to a list of characters and then modify the list in place.

```
char_list = list(txt)
for i, char in enumerate(char_list):
    if char in string.punctuation:
         char_list[i] = " "
return "".join(char_list)
```

Better still would be to use the string modules translate function:

```
import string
x = 'this.! is my ^$input string?'
trans_tab = string.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' ' * len(string.punctuation))
print string.translate(x, trans_tab)
print x
print string.translate(x, None, string.punctuation)
```

### Output:

```
this   is my   input string 
this.! is my ^$input string?
this is my input string
```

Note that the translate function makes a copy and does not modify your original string.